# How do I display scores in rows of 5?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am fairly new to c++ programming and I need help with my program. I am supposed to display a set of scores from a text file but I don't know how to display them in rows of 5.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code so far:

```
//Create a Vector to hold a set of exam scores.Write a program to do the following tasks: 1. Read exam scores into a vector from Scores.txt 
//2. Display scores in rows of five(5) scores.
//3. Calculate average score and display.
//4. Find the median score and display.
//5. Compute the Standard Deviation and display

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{   
    const int array_size = 36; // array size
    int numbers[array_size]; //array with 36 elements
    int count = 0;
    ifstream inputfile; //input file into stream object
    //open file
    inputfile.open("Scores.txt");
    //read file
    while (count < array_size && inputfile >> numbers[count])
        count++;
    //close file
    inputfile.close(); 
    //display numbers read
    cout << "Scores:\n";
    for (count = 0; count < array_size; count++)
        cout << numbers[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
int column_count = 5;
for (count = 0; count < array_size; count++) {
    cout << numbers[count] << " ";
    if ( count % column_count == column_count - 1 ) {
         cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function

```
cout << setw(x);
```

which will make the next item you print, so

```
cout << setw(10) << "hello" << "bye now";
```

would give you

```
     hellobye now
```

and if you want to left-justify, use

```
cout << left;
cout << setw(10) << "hello" << "bye now";
```

to give

```
hello     bye now
```